# How can I import a class's member variable instead of the class?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, import

Not sure if this is possible but I'm wanting to import a class's member variable instead of the class itself to minimize the amount of code I'd have to change.  When I import the class itself I have to then go prefix my functions with the member variable.  Is there a way to import the member variable where I would just use the member function for the member variable without having to specify the member variable?

**Page File**

```
Imports MyProject.cMyClass 

Public Class myWebForm
       Inherits myInheritedClass

Public Shared Page_Load(...) Handles Me.Load

      MemberVariableIncMyClass.FunctionIWishToUse()
```

**What I would like to do**

```
Imports MyProject.cMyClass.MemberVariableIncMyClass 

Public Class myWebForm
       Inherits myInheritedClass

Public Shared Page_Load(...) Handles Me.Load

       FunctionIWishToUse()
```

I would like to not have to have "cMyClass" specified before "FunctionIWishToUse()". Not sure that this is possible though.

Comment: As far as I know, you import namespaces, not classes. Also, if your `myWebForm` class inherited from `cMyClass`, all instance members of `cMyClass` would be "replicated" in your class, so you could use them. Maybe if you show us some code of your classes we'll be able to help better, and surely by studying OOP further you'll solve these problems better too.

Comment: Well I can't inherit with it because I'm already inheriting from MasterPages.  Now I realize there are some proper ways to correct that but I was just seeing if there was something I was missing to minimize the changes to the project I'm working with when converting it to masterpages.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Can you be more specific which type and method you're trying to call?

Comment: the only way to call a function without specifying container prefix from anywhere is to put the function in `Module`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With MemberVariableIncMyClass

     .FunctionIWishToUse()
     .OtherFunction()
     .Etc()

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import namespaces or namespace.element, where element is a programming container, such as class, structures, modules, interfaces and enumerations.

You can import below that level, so you cannot import a class member variable.